# Stop powershell script counting after it gets to three

Tags: powershell

I have a script that counts how many times a certain word occurs within a file. With the file it keeps adding words and each time the powershell is suppose to count the occurance. However I want to it stop counting once its identified a specific word has been added three times eg:

apple
apple
apple
banana
banana
apple

I want it to stop counting once its identified apple 3 times and not count it as 4. this is the powershell script that i'm using :

```
    $ht=@{}
$Output=switch(gc c:\temp\LimitCount.txt){ {($ht.values|sort -Descending|select -first 1) -eq 3}{break}
 {$_ -match '^. +user:(.+)$' -and [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ht.(([regex]"^(?:. +user:)(.+)$").matches($_).groups[1].value))}{$ht.(([regex]"^(?:. +user:)(.+)$").matches($_).groups   [1].value)=0}
 {$_ -match '^. +user:(.+)$' -and $ht.(([regex]"^(?:. +user:)(.+)$").matches($_).groups[1].value) -eq 3}{continue}
{$_ -match '^. +user:(.+)$'}{$ht.(([regex]"^(?:. +user:)(.+)$").matches($_).groups[1].value)++;([regex]"^(?:. +user:)(.+)$").matches($_).groups[1].value;continue}
 default {$_}
}
"Unfiltered results and count:"
$output|group -NoElement
$output|Where{$ht.keys -contains $_}|group -NoElement
```

Comment: Stop for that specific word, or stop entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you didn't respond to my comment, but we'll assume you want no more than 3 of any single match. What I will do is make an empty hashtable, and run a Switch command on the contents of the file and capture the results in an array

The first validation will check if the string matches the regex, and if that matched text is already in the hashtable. If it does match, and is not in the hashtable it adds it to the hashtable.

The second validation checks if the string matches the regex, and if the hashtable entry is equal to 3. If it is then it skips to the next line of the text file.

The third validation simply checks if the string matches the regex, and if it does it increments the hashtable entry for that match by one, and passes the matched text.

The fourth validation is the default, and if no other validation occurs then it simply passes the line along un-altered.

Then you can output that array, or filter it for only things that matched your regex. The code would look something like this:

```
$ht=@{}
$Output=switch(gc c:\temp\test.txt){
    {$_ -match '^. +user:(.+)$' -and [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ht.(([regex]"^(?:. +user:)(.+)$").matches($_).groups[1].value))}{$ht.(([regex]"^(?:. +user:)(.+)$").matches($_).groups[1].value)=0}
    {$_ -match '^. +user:(.+)$' -and $ht.(([regex]"^(?:. +user:)(.+)$").matches($_).groups[1].value) -eq 3}{continue}
    {$_ -match '^. +user:(.+)$'}{$ht.(([regex]"^(?:. +user:)(.+)$").matches($_).groups[1].value)++;([regex]"^(?:. +user:)(.+)$").matches($_).groups[1].value;continue}
    default {$_}
}
"Unfiltered results and count:"
$output|group -NoElement
"Filtered for only matched items:"
$output|Where{$ht.keys -contains $_}|group -NoElement
```

Given an input of:

```
A user:Apple
A user:Apple
A user:Banana
Shiney tacos!
A user:Orange
A user:Banana
A user:Apple
A user:Orange
A user:Orange
A user:Apple
A user:Apple
A user:Apple
A user:Apple
A user:Apple
```

You get an output of:

```
Unfiltered results and count:
Count Name                     
----- ----                     
    3 Apple                    
    2 Banana                   
    1 Shiney tacos!            
    3 Orange                   
Filtered for only matched items:
    3 Apple                    
    2 Banana                   
    3 Orange
```

If you want to stop once you reach 3 of any match you can add the following line immediately before the first validation:

```
    {($ht.values|sort -Descending|select -first 1) -eq 3}{break}
```

Comment: thank you sorry for responding late, this is what i wanted to stop after it matches more than 3 for each

Comment: how can i modify the code so it only counts up to 3 and stop instead of creating a new user with the same name. e.g. i have 4 apples and its counting as 3 apples then on a new line it counts the other apple as 1 apple. but i only want one outcome for apple as in: 3 apples and stops there?

Comment: This doesn't go past 3 for anything, so I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry i dont think i explained clearly so it doesnt go past 3 instead in creates another user for apple on a new line. So i have apple, apple, apple, apple. The outcome is 3 user apple, 1 user apple. I dont want it to have the additional 1 user apple...does this make sense?

Comment: You will have to update your question with your code. What you are saying doesn't make sense without code to reference.

Comment: The code above says nothing about creating users. I can't help you if you don't give me actual context to work with. My code outputs 3 apple. Not 3 apple, and then 1 apple, just 3 apple. So without seeing your code that is returning something different I can't help you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion and thank you for still replying..I misused the word create i meant output 3 apples and then 1 apple but i dont want the other 1 apple to be outputted i just want it to stop once it identifies 3 apple and omit count the rest of the apples.

Comment: I think we have a communication problem. What you are describing is what my script does. Perhaps you are seeing additional results because you are outputting the results twice. Try removing either the last line, or the second to the last line in your script above and see if that provides what you want.

Comment: Thank you I will do that you are most likely correct. Apologies for the confusion.